# iris data set K_means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

the question is why im getting 0.00 accuracy

```
iris = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')


feature_cols = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.loc[:, iris.columns != 'species'],
iris['species'], test_size=0.30 , random_state=0)


k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
k_means.fit(X_train)


score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,k_means.predict(X_test))
print('Accuracy:{0:f}'.format(score))

print(k_means.predict(X_test))
print(k_means.labels_[:])
print(y_test[:])
```

the problem is that im getting the accuracy 0.0

```
Accuracy:0.000000

[0 0 1 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 2 0 1
 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 1]

[0 2 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 2 0 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0 2 0
 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 0 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 2 0 1
 0 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 1 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 1]

114     virginica

62     versicolor

33         setosa
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: You didn't post a question

Comment: why im getting 0.0 accuracy

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that kmeans will predict the cluster (0,1 or 2). But they are not necessarily labeled the same as your labels. For example - maybe kmeans will map a sample to cluster 0, which is species=1.
You have to check the label of each cluster and compare y_test with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using accuracy as if you are dealing with a classification task. KMeans is a method for clustering (unsupervised learning), therefore it will build cluster and not predict classes. As someone else already indicated the effect is that the numbers of the clusters are more or less random. So if you have – which is only true for academic and/or toy problems – a classification to compare the clustering with you have to perform an additional step.

1. Use a cluster algorithm to build clusters
2. Look which cluster has the biggest overlap with a given class set
3. Reassign the numbers regarding the overlaps
4. Look how much clusters and classes are differing

This is common when it comes to teaching machine learning. As well as it is common to use the iris data because it is quite easy to build a perfect classification model (supervised) but it is a totally different story when it comes to clustering (unsupervised). If you look at your KMeans results keep in mind that KMeans always builds convex clusters regarding the used norm/metric.